# Поменять местами в массиве числа с противоположными знаками с учетом перестановки не более одного раза

Tags: javascript, массивы

Поменять местами в одномерном массиве противоположные по знаку элементы (например, 5.7 и -5.7), с учетом перестановки кожного элемента не более одного раза.

первую часть условия выполнил, а вот со второй возникли траблы
[4,4,-4,-4,0,8] - исходный
[4,-4,4,-4,0,8] - надо или же любое другое изменение, главное чтобы оно больше не повторялось

```
for(let i =0; i<mass.length; i++){
   for(let j=6; j>=0; j--){
        if(Math.abs(mass[i])===Math.abs(mass[j])){
            mass[i]= mass[i]*-1
            mass[j]= mass[j]*-1
           break;
        } 
   }
}

console.log(mass)
```

Comment: откуда взялось `let j=6`? Добавь пример входного и выходного массивов. Что делать если будет три числа с разными знаками?

Comment: на это не смотри, там масс ленс

Comment: Добавь пример входного и выходного массивов. Что делать если будет три числа с разными знаками?

Comment: там только один массив

Comment: если будет две пары одинаковых противоположных чисел, то знаки их поменяются, этого пытаюсь избежать

Comment: Добавь пример входного и выходного массивов: исходное состояние и состояние которое требуется получить

Comment: выше я спрашивал не про пары. А про три значения например `[1,-1,1]` или `[1,1,-1]` - какой результат должен быть?

Comment: [4,4,-4,-4,0,8] -  исходный [4,-4,4,-4,0,8] надо

Comment: отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: почему `[4,-4,4,-4,0,8]` а не например `[-4,4,4,-4,0,8]`?

Comment: такое тоже может быть

Comment: главное чтобы такое изменение больше не повторялось

Comment: что значит больше не повторялось? Если нет четких критериев - то задачу в принципе невозможно решить

Comment: ну чтобы подобное изменение произошло только раз, в случае если будут найдены такие же противоположные элементы их пропустит и приступит к следующим

Comment: Второй массив можно использовать?

Comment: да, конечно можно

Comment: Ну тогда за чем дело стало? В первом проверяйте, во второй записывайте с обратным знаком, в первом обнуляйте

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительный массив используется как хранилище признаков "уже двигали"

```
for(let i =0; i<mass.length-1; i++){
   if(temp[i]==0){
      for(let j=i+1; i<mass.length; j++){
          if(temp[j]==0 && mass[i] == -mass[j]){
              mass[i] = -mass[i]
              mass[j] = -mass[j]
              temp[j] = 1
              temp[i] = 1
              break;
          } 
       }
    }
```

Comment: элементы которые не берут участие в изменении знаков должны остаться

Comment: Ладно, тогда альтернативный путь уже написал, пусть он остаётся. В том способе достаточно добавить копирование ненулевого mass[i] после цикла, но всё равно там работы больше.